# How to add multiple data to recycler with data from firebase using ArrayList<CustomClass>

Tags: android, arraylist, kotlin, android-recyclerview

**EDIT: SOLVED([RecyclerView shows just one item from Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50271655/recyclerview-shows-just-one-item-from-firebase))**

Currently, my code is able to retrieve data from firebase and put it into my ArrayList. But the problem is, it can only put one data to the ArrayList and pass it to the recycler view adapter.

**My Code to get from firebase and populate data to ArrayList**

```
    private fun getFromFirebase() {
        val currentUserUID = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().uid.toString()
        val ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
        ref.child("users").child(currentUserUID).child("foods").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {

            }

            override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
                setHasFixedSize(true)
                recyclerview.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@FoodListActivity)
                p0.children.forEach {
                    Log.d("getFood", it.toString())
                    val foodData = it.getValue(Foods::class.java)
                    if (foodData != null) {
                        val foodList = ArrayList<Foods>()
                        val adapter = ListAdapter(foodList)
                        foodList.add(foodData)
                        recyclerview.adapter = adapter

                    }
                }

            }

        })}}
```

**And here's my adapter**

```
class listAdapter(val food : ArrayList<Foods>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<listAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return food.count()
        Log.d("getFood", food.size.toString())
    }

}
```

The problem here is when I do Log.d("getFood", it.toString()) I can get all the item from database, but when I do Log.d("getFood", food.size.toString()) I only get 1, and on my recyclerView, it will also only appear one item, which every time happen to be the second one on the data structure, the "mild spicy" one.

[**Here's my Firebase Data Structure**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bmb31.png)

Answer (score 0):

Change `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` to `ValueEventListener` 
also you have to call `adapter.notifydatasetchanged` after this line `recyclerview.adapter = adapter`

```
private fun getFromFirebase() {
    val currentUserUID = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().uid.toString()
    val ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
    ref.child("users").child(currentUserUID).child("foods").addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
        override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {

        }

        override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
            setHasFixedSize(true)
            recyclerview.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@FoodListActivity)
            p0.children.forEach {
                Log.d("getFood", it.toString())
                val foodData = it.getValue(Foods::class.java)
                if (foodData != null) {
                    val foodList = ArrayList<Foods>()
                    val adapter = ListAdapter(foodList)
                    foodList.add(foodData)
                    recyclerview.adapter = adapter
                    recyclerview.adapter.notifydatasetchanged
                }
            }

        }

    })}
```

Comment: Could you please share your snapshot structure from firebase

Comment: by using this code, the problem is still there, my data structure is in the  **Here's my Firebase Data Structure** link

Comment: I try deleting the second item on my database and the 1st item will show up on my recyclerView, basically my recycler view currently only show 1 item and will most likely be the last one from the database.

Comment: i mean to share the  database on the firebase (ScreenShot) 
from the data like this 

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xTL97TsrrriCHFvoIIHjRUUadgboR_39/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I try to google similar issue, but most of them are having the problem because of the recycler view height, but that's not likely my case I guess

Comment: SOLVED: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50271655/recyclerview-shows-just-one-item-from-firebase